# En un Modelo(MVC) hacer consulta a una Vista(SQL) o consultar varias tablas

Tags: java, mvc, diseño, jtable

Buenos días.
Estoy adaptando mi proyecto a MVC y tengo una duda, en un formulario necesito recuperar los datos de 3 tablas. Tengo una vista(SQL) ya creada donde puedo crear el metodo obtenerRegistro() del Modelo 'miembroDao(Data Access Object)' pero no puedo crear los métodos insertarRegistro() ni eliminarRegistro() porque no puedo modificar de una vista(SQL).

¿Entonces sería mas correcto crear los 3 modelos para cada tabla o habría otra solución?

PersonaDao ---> Tabla Persona.
DirecciónDao ---> Tabla Dirección.
HistorialDao ---> Tabla Historial.

En el controlador tendría que llamar a los 3 modelos y tendría que realizar 3 consultas, con la vista(SQL) manera solo 1 pero no podría modificar.

Espero haber sido lo mas claro posible, si hay alguna duda en la explicación coméntenmelo

Answer (score 1):

Sencillo puedes crear un BO (business object) o mejor aún un TO (transfer object), según el patrón que elijas tu DAO construirá un BO con los 3 modelos o un TO con los datos más relevantes de los 3 modelos:

Formulario - > Vista,
TO, BO , Pojos -> Modelo,
DAO -> Controlador

Comment: He encontrdo esta págna web, voy a documentarme con lo que me has comentado a ver si me sirve de ayuda. Muchas gracias por ayudarme https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/transfer_object_pattern.htm

Comment: El TO(transfer object) es como el VO por lo que he visto, finalmente voy a consultar la Vista para mostrarla en una tabla porque no quiero modificar datos en la tabla, seguidamente entraré en un formulario y ahí buscaré los modelos 1 a 1. Cuanto termine el proyecto lo compartiré.